# Why does jQuery.fadeTo() scroll my horizontal page to the top (=to the left)?

Tags: jquery, fadein, horizontalscrollview, fadeto, page-jump

I am running a *horizontal* website. I have a gallery which shows only one picture. For not having to refresh the whole page when changing the displayed picture, I used jQuery fadeIn, load and fadeOut. This worked nice in Safari, but in Firefox it jumps to the left edge of the page. So I googled the problem, and I tried to give the parent div a fix width & height and position:relative, while the swapped div also got a fix width/height and position:absolute. This didn't work. I found a blogpost where a similar problem was described and the solution shall be to use fadeTo. Now this is my code and it doesn't work either:

```
$("#gal").fadeTo(200, 0, function () {
    $("#gal").empty().load(galleryimage,false).fadeTo(200, 1);
});
```

Where is my fault?
Greetings!

Comment: Can you please post a JSFiddle?

Comment: I didn't know this before, I hope this will help you. I can add more code if you need it.
http://jsfiddle.net/wkUx9/

Comment: JSFiddle's don't support PHP, I'd suggest changing it.

Comment: OK, I added some placeholders instead. Do you need to know how I realised the horizontal scroll?

Comment: It's not showing that you updated the fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to click on Update.
http://jsfiddle.net/wkUx9/2/

Comment: Why is there already an `img` tag in the body with the same source?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16443/discussion-between-user1478344-and-charlie)

Comment: unfortunately the problem still remains